# Does multi-platter hard-drive use all of their heads to read simultaneously?

Tags: hard-drive

Suppose we have a harddisk with 2 platters with characteristics below:

> Rotational rate: 10, 000 RPM
>   Avg sectors/track: 1000
>   Surfaces: 4
>   Sector size: 512 bytes

I was reading "Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective 2ed" when I found that it calculates transfer time as if it only uses ONE head to read a sector.
If that's the case, why not use 4 heads to write(read) on 4 surfaces? So when I write a 2K bytes file, each head should only need to wait for the platters to rotate just one sector length instead of 4, thus reducing the transfer time by a factor of 4.
Or even redesign sector to make each sector on one cylinder but on 4 tracks residing same position respectively on 4 surfaces. Each one of (512/4) bytes. So when the hd needs to read a sector of 512 bytes, we only need the disk to rotate roughly 1/4 compare to original time.
 
The idea looks like RAID 0.

Comment: I don't know what is actually done, but I can say that something that is usually wanted is file contiguity. That can't happen if parts of the files are written on different platters.

Comment: In fact, that doesn't have anything to do with file contiguity. It's only a way to organize the internal mechanism when implementing a sector(the last part of the question). In this scenario, all data in a "logical sector" is on one cylinder, and the actual data splits in 4 parts landing on the same physical position on different surface. This is within a sector, when fragmentation is about sectors placement of a file.

Comment: Only one R/W head is used at a time. Period.  The only exception would be a dual-ported drive, and those are rare.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing and asked [over on electronics.stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/643792/why-do-hard-disks-use-only-one-head-at-a-time/643793), but I found an article that explains it that looks like the author knows what he's talking about.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To read or write all heads at once would require duplicating all the circuitry involved - head amplifiers, bitstream decoders, even the microprocessors and cache memory. I don't know how disks are actually designed, but it seems unlikely to me, especially given the price pressures in the industry. Besides, even the stream from a single platter is likely to be near the interface limit - it's the seeking and rotational delays that kill you.

Comment: “even the stream from a single platter is likely to be near the interface limit”? WTF. The 1.5gbps SATA interface from the year 2000 could have handled the 150MiB/s stream from a typical HDD released in 2022. I don’t think platter speeds have ever approached interface limits in the last couple of decades and I don’t think it will ever happen in the future now that 6gb SATA and 12gb SAS are dying and the newest HDDs are going straight to PCIe

Answer (score 6):

I think that's already how it works :

> ## Cylinders
>
> A cylinder comprises the same track number on each platter, spanning
>   all such tracks across each platter surface that is able to store data
>   (without regard to whether or not the track is "bad"). Thus, it is a
>   three-dimensional structure. Any track comprising part of a specific
>   cylinder can be written to and read from while the actuator assembly
>   remains stationary, **and one way in which hard drive manufacturers have
>   increased drive access speed has been by increasing the number of
>   platters which can be read at the same time.**
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector#Cylinders

EDIT

this quote from Wikipedia don't say it all, the guys from [pcguide.com](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/op/heads/opNumber-c.html) clearly say :

> Only one head can read from or write to the hard disk at a given time.
>   Special circuitry is used to control which head is active at any given
>   time.

so this is for the low/middle-end HDD, **BUT** I came across few OLD discussions [here](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware3/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=98440&ixReplies=23) and [here](http://forums.storagereview.com/index.php/topic/4915-when-will-hard-drives-have-internal-raid-like-features/) where they are referring to the technique you are describing as **"internal RAID"** and I actually don't know enough about today's HDD technology.

Comment: Interesting quote, where's it from?

Comment: It's from wikipedia, with no reference though.

Comment: From your [link](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware3/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=98440&ixReplies=23), John Rose said "Maybe it's because a certain number of hard drive sectors are always marked as "bad", since no drive will ever have all their billions of sectors functioning perfectly.  If you did the "internal RAID" thing, if one sector failed, the drive would need to mark it as bad on all 2 or 3 platters.which I guess would really start cutting down on usable drive capacity...". I think it makes sense too.

Comment: "Internal RAID" is a joke.  Trying to achieve "redundancy" by using the same physical HDD accomplishes nothing.  Bottom line: The (single-port) HDD has only one set of R/W electronics on the controller board.  Therefore only one R/W head can be used at a time.

Answer (score 3):

In the Olden Days when hard drives used stepper motors, they could read all the platters at the same time.

But that hasn't been the case for a long time. Finding the right track is a matter of playing hotter/colder hide and seek with voice coils. That can't be done on all platters at the same time. Tracks are too small to be precisely in the same position on all platters so they have to seek individually.

Comment: _"[...] they could read all the platters at the same time."_  Well, maybe they could have, but very very few drives were ever built that way.

Comment: -1 for pure fiction.

Comment: [This article](https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2019/09/hard-disk-geometry-microbenchmarking/) agrees with this answer, I think this is the correct answer. See subheader "Cylinders" in the article.